# copy data from 1 table to another table with checking for equal data

Tags: php, mysql, migration, opencart, prestashop

I have been working on migrating a webshop. The company that did this did something wrong and I want to fix it myself.

**The problem is:**
I have 2 tables 1 from the old webshop (let's call this one `A`) and one from the new one (and we call this one `B`).

Now the short description needs to be copied from `table A` to `table B`. The column name in `table A` is `meta_description` and in `table B` it is `description_short`. but I do not want to just copy and be done. Because when I do that everything will not be in order. Cause both tables are sorted differently.

I got this far:

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO pskd_product_lang (description_short)
VALUES ($desc)";
    // use exec() because no results are returned
    $conn->exec($sql);
    echo "New record created successfully";
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}

$conn = null;
```

where `$desc` is made here:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM oc_product_description"; 
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th></tr>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $name = $row["name"];
        $desc = $row["meta_description"];
        echo "<tr><td>".$name."</td><td>".$desc."</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

as you can see the target `table (B)` is called `pskd_product_lang`
The source `table (A)` is called `oc_product_description` I tried were statements and a lot of other things I found on the internet but nothing worked...

If someone could help me out or point me in the right direction I would be grateful!!

Thanks in advance

Comment: See about prepared and bound queries.

Comment: Tables aren't, technically, sorted unless you sort them when you do a query. There must be an identifier in each of the tables that uniquely identifies each product. That is what you need to retrieve and use to "tie" them together and update only one row at a time. [Edit]ing your question and including the table definitions might help us be able to help you further.

Comment: Wait, what? Are you trying to use a plain variable from inside a `while` in a whole another part of the code? You will only insert the last result, since it will be the value the variable will have when leaving the loop and reaching the next part of the code. You need to insert value while inside the `while`, or store each value from the `while` to an array and then do a `foreach` and insert every value.